# Tableau - multiple columns with True and False values

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, case-statement

I have 10 columns with True and False values. I would like to create a dashboard where if one column is True and another column is also True, a graph displays a count in that column. For example: if column A is True, column B if False, column C is True - then it would return a count for column C.

I would like a parameter setup where a user can select one of the ten columns and it would show in a bar chart the count of other columns that are True when that column is True.

The first part is where I am having trouble - I haven't gotten to the second part yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Data like this sometimes comes up naturally in survey results (e.g., select all choices that apply answers) A great place to learn about visualizing survey data is Steve Wexler’s blog http://www.datarevelations.com and any of his videos at Tableau conferences.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I can get the data to show the count/% of each column that is marked as True. But how do I get it to show the other columns that are marked as True only when the column that I select is True. I don't think this was addressed on that blog.

Comment: can you add sample data, will surely try to help